# .2015: When last did both New/Full moon in a fort-night cause an Eclipse?

Tags: solar-eclipse, lunar-eclipse

Going through http://earthsky.org/…/dates-of-next-lunar-and-solar-eclipses I made the (what was for me - momentous) discovery that

March 20, 2015 - New moon - is a Solar Eclipse, and that the succeeding
April 04, 2015 - Full moon - heralds a Lunar Eclipse.

- Is it common that both New/Full moon in a fort-night cause an eclipse?
- When was the last time an Eclipse occurred back-to-back on a consecutive New Moon/Full Moon?

Comment: There is something strange about your dates. All the news has a solar eclipse on the spring equinox, March 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/10-facts-solar-eclipse-march-2015.html):

> Another oddity of nature is that solar eclipses and lunar eclipses tend to come in pairs – a solar eclipse always takes place about two weeks before or after a lunar eclipse.

And [here](http://vnatsci.ltu.edu/s_schneider/astro/wbstla2k/mytalk/leclipse.shtml):

> Rules of Eclipses (Solar and Lunar) ... Eclipses tend to go in pairs or threes : solar-lunar-solar. Lunar eclipse always preceeded by or followed by a solar eclipse (two weeks between them)

So, seems like a totally common thing.

P.S. The previous pair was first lunar on Oct 8, 2014, and then solar on Oct 23rd.